# How can I declare a two dimensional array in React?

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array

I try to do this:

```
 getInitialState: function(){
    return({
        people: [] .... or people: [{id: "", key: ""}] or people: [[id: ][key: ]]
    });
},
```

so I have an id and a key every person and I want to store it like this.

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Comment: error issue in the declaration

Comment: I saw the declaration... What is the relationship between React and two dimensional array ?

Comment: i have a function with a query, and then i would like to push this two elements(id, key) to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error. Try:

```
getInitialState () { 
  return {
    people: []
  }; 
}
```

This creates an empty array in your initial state. You can just populate your `people` array normally like so:

```
let p = this.state.people.slice();
p.push({id: "", key: ""});
this.setState({people: p});
```

The first line creates a copy of your `people`. You then push a new item to the temporary array. Finally you replace the old `people` state with the new one.

A one-liner way of doing this:

```
this.setState({people: this.state.people.concat([{id: "", key: ""}])});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't push the two values to the array

Comment: @Zimzo. Do you want the values in the initial state or *after* the component has mounted?

Comment: After the component has mounted
@Chris